# AMPPS PHP 5.6 OPCache disabled

Tags: php, moodle, opcache, ampps

while trying to install Moodle, I got a message saying i should check the PHP settings to enable OPCache. 
I followed the [instructions](https://docs.moodle.org/33/en/OPcache) and since I am on MacOS it says I have to 
"*use the zend_extension configuration to load the OPcache extension into PHP by adding to php.ini.*".

The problem is I can't find anywhere the opcache.so lib. I've looked in all the subfolders of `AMPPS/php-5.6/` as well as other folders from AMPPS but it's nowhere to be found.

I've tried just enabling all the config keys with the suggested values in that link and restarting Apache but Moodle still displays the same message.

Looking at the PHPInfo page I see the following in the configure command section:

```
'--libdir=/Applications/AMPPS/php-5.6/lib' '--enable-opcache=no'
```

Does this mean the PHP 5.6 packaged with AMPPS was compiled without OPCache? If so how do I get around this?
Or am I simply missing something?

Comment: did you ever find an answer for this?

Comment: sorry mate, didn't find a solution for this, the moodle installation can proceed without it and on the production server it was working fine so I didn't waste more time on it.